# Program to copy every line in a text file that contains a specific string to a new text file

Tags: .net, vb.net, text-files

The title explains everything and I found ways to read the text file and search for a string but I didn't find how to copy the whole line that contains that string to a new text file.

```
Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText("My file path")
Dim Lookfor as string = "word"

If FindString.Contains(Lookfor) then....

End If
```

Here is the code. It's too simple so in the time it find the word in a line. I want it to copy the whole line that contains that word to a new text file and actually I read that this code load all the text in the text file in one line in the memory and search for the word in it so I think it will not work the way I want.

Comment: Show the code you've tried and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Show some input & output sample too.

Comment: Here is the code it's just read all the text in the text file and search for tge word  it's just two lines

Comment: I really want to know why peaple here downvote me what iam telling wrong? Iam just a newbie that try to learn some coding is this a bad thing?!

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but I can tell you why you've gotten them: Stack Overflow is not a service where we help you write code or find tutorials for you. We're here to help you resolve a **specific** issue or question. Therefore you must always show us _**your research**_, what _**you've done so far**_ in trying to solve the problem yourself, and _**where you are stuck**_. For guidelines on how to ask proper question please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for leting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion starts from what is published on MSDN, a good starting point for all newbies, in this case look for the `Streamreader.ReadLine`

```
Dim aLine As String
Dim strReader As New StreamReader(textReaderText)
Dim Lookfor as string = "word"
While not strReader.EndofStream
    aLine = strReader.ReadLine()
         If aLine.Contains(Lookfor) then....
             'your stuff here
         End IF
End While
```

What the code does is to read from the stream one line at a time and if contains your match, it does stuff

Comment: Thanks too much for help ^_^

Comment: the line (strReader.EndofStream) gives me the error ("End of Stream" is not a member of "StringReader") iam using visual studio 2015

Comment: Yeah, it's a member of StreamReader. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for help :)